# How can I insert or remove a tab before / after every new line in a string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following string, as a selection in a textarea:

> "I want to insert \n a tab after every newline in the this selection. \n I also want to know how to do the opposite, removing the tab before each newline in this selection."

And a simplified example of the code involved:

```
var userWantsToIndentSelection = true,
userWantsToOutdentSelection = false,
start = this.selectionStart,
end = this.selectionEnd,
selection = text.slice(start,end),
newline = /\r|\n/.exec(selection);

if(newline){
    if (userWantsToIndentSelection){

        // add tabs after each newline

    }
    else if (userWantsToOutdentSelection) {

        // remove tabs before each newline

    }
}

if(!newline){

    // Handling just one line (cursor at front of line, no selection) is simple.
    // Perhaps I don't need a special handler though
    // and can use the new line handler for single and multiple line selections.
    // Mention it in your answer if you like.

}
```

**How can I insert or remove a tab before / after every new line in a string with Javascript?**

Comment: I haven't messed with Regex much, and while that might be a solution, I was hoping I could maybe use the slice() map() or filter() functions that I've been reading about.

Comment: selection = "\t" + selection.split("\n").join("\n\t") will add a line. reverse the quotes in split/join to undo.

Comment: @dandavis post that as an answer, it's very simple and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regex `src.replace(/^/gm, "\t");`

`^` matches the start of line

The `m` tells the regex engine to use the multi-line mode so that `^` will match each line and not only the start of the string.